# Application of `SSet` in Agda

Tags: agda, applications

Is there any presentable work that makes essential use of `SSet` in Agda? I kind of get the theory, but I'm not sure about the practical value of this. The documentation is currently not very helpful.

Comment: Do their usages in cubical suffice?

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/test/Succeed/SST.agda?

Comment: Also https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/5944

Comment: @ice1000 Which usage? Is there a medium or large sized repo using them?

Comment: No, for now I guess they're only used in cubical primitives, not the cubical library.

Comment: In this experimantal library about 2LTT, SSet plays an essential role. See https://github.com/ElifUskuplu/2LTT-Agda

Comment: @phdstudent Cool! Can you write that as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SSet provides another universe for not-necessarily fibrant types, it is useful when one is working on 2LTT. You can see one of the experimental library about 2LTT here : https://github.com/ElifUskuplu/2LTT-Agda .